# ASPNET Zero Xamarin.forms IOS Error "System.Exception: Set configuration before using remote localization!"

Tags: xamarin.forms, aspnetzero

How can I resolve the "ComponentActivatorException" error in ASP.NET Zero when running my Xamarin.Forms iOS app, which shows the following message: "System.Exception: Set configuration before using remote localization!"? The app keeps initializing and then disconnects from the debugger.

2023-04-24 23:03:13.323 MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Mobile.iOS[3710:1201441] Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException: ComponentActivator: could not instantiate MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Views.LoginView ---> System.Exception: Set configuration before using remote localization!
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.ProvideValue (System.Object& value, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, System.Object source, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName) [0x000ac] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:279
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000ea] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:117
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000ac] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:158
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor
visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:209
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext visitorContext, System.Boolean useDesignProperties) [0x0008b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:236
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml, System.Reflection.Assembly rootAssembly, System.Boolean useDesignProperties) [0x000a2] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:104
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml, System.Boolean useDesignProperties) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:77
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00029] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:73
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:

I tried running the application and expected it to load the LoginView but it never loads the page after launching the splashscreen.

Comment: https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/5655/MobileDroid-not-deploying-to-device-emulator-or-physical-No-errors-just-hangs

Comment: Tried this and it's not working. Remember my Android app works well and the problem is on IOS

Comment: Hi @Jason tried setting my local ip address just like the thread suggests but still getting the same problem. I have the host project running on azure. Is there a way to connect IOS directly to the online host ?